# Nested linq to entities sum strange result

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I need a smart head who can explain me what in my first-try query went wrong ;)

At first I've tried to do all in one query which I considered trivial (**freeArea1**) but I got suspicious results so I've tried 'brute force' debug approach (**foreach**) and there the score was right. After few tries I decided to split my query into two (**freeArea2** and **freeArea3**) hoping for some explanation. But again *freeArea2 - freeArea3 == dif* so both subsums were fine...

So what I'm asking about is **why?** my first query gives me irrational result.

(FA1 < 0; FA2 > FA3)

```
var user = db.UserSet.First(u => u.Login == HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
var freeArea1 = db.CadastralParcelSet
                  .Where(cp => cp.UserId == user.Id)
                  .Sum(cp => cp.CadastralParcelArea - cp.AgriculturalParcels.Sum(ap => ap.AgriculturalParcelArea));

var freeArea2 = db.CadastralParcelSet
                  .Where(cp => cp.UserId == user.Id)
                  .Sum(cp => cp.CadastralParcelArea);

var freeArea3 = db.CadastralParcelSet
                  .Where(cp => cp.UserId == user.Id)
                  .Sum(cp => cp.AgriculturalParcels.Sum(ap => ap.AgriculturalParcelArea));

decimal dif = 0;
foreach (var cp in db.CadastralParcelSet.Where(c => c.UserId == user.Id))
{
    var carea = cp.CadastralParcelArea;
    var aarea = cp.AgriculturalParcels.Sum(a => a.AgriculturalParcelArea);
    dif += carea - aarea;
}
```

Comment: suspicious <=> (FA1 < 0; FA2 > FA3)

FA1 = -162, FA2 = 956, FA3 = 587, dif = 369

CPA and APA are both decimals

Comment: Are any of these NULLable? Quite often the start of 'strange' results.

Comment: No, both ain't. What I managed to find is that in sql sum on empty collections, and some of them are empty, might return NULL sothat some positive subsums could have been omitted. That is the reason I've asked my question. I don't need this to work since my alternative solutions do. I just want to know what am I missing. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. I think I've found my answer. Like I'd previously suggested in my comment:

if:

```
cp.AgriculturalParcels.Count() == 0
```

then probably this:

```
cp.AgriculturalParcels.Sum(ap => ap.AgriculturalParcelArea)
```

returns *NULL* and whole subsum:

```
.Sum(cp => cp.CadastralParcelArea - cp.AgriculturalParcels.Sum(ap => ap.AgriculturalParcelArea));
```

seems to be omitted...

**SOLUTION**:

```
var freeArea = db.CadastralParcelSet
                 .Where(cp => (cp.UserId == user.Id))
                 .Sum(cp => cp.CadastralParcelArea - (cp.AgriculturalParcels.Count() == 0 ? 0 : cp.AgriculturalParcels.Sum(ap => ap.AgriculturalParcelArea)));
```

Comment: Another 'fun' fact is that outside LINQ (inside 'foreach') cp.AgriculturalParcels.Sum(ap => ap.AgriculturalParcelArea) does not return NULL even if cp.AgriculturalParcels.Count() equals 0.

Comment: you can also use `cp.AgriculturalParcels.Sum(cp => (decimal?)ap.AgriculturalParcelArea) ?? 0`

Comment: You have used 'cp' variable name in lambda instead of 'ap' but indeed it works and looks somehow better even if still not obvious